# Mopidy with PulseAudio sound over TCP

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, alsa, pulseaudio, mopidy

So I have been struggling with this for a while now and looked everywhere for solutions.

I have installed Mopidy with Spotify extension on my Raspberry Pi 3B but I can't seem to get the pulseaudio over TCP to work. I am able to play music on the web extension but I don't get any some from my bluetooth speaker.

I have added

```
[audio]
mixer = software
mixer_volume = 50
output = pulsesink server=127.0.0.1
#buffer_time =
```

To my Mopidy config and also tried with alsasink

I have added

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1
```

To my pulse `default.conf`

What am I missing?